# Book Searching in Complex Analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request

I'm searching for a problem book in complex analysis published by MIR. It was recommended by my professor (when I asked for a Demidovich equivalent in the field), but he did not remember the exact name (possibly "*Ejercicios de Analise Complexa*" - Exercises in Complex Analysis) nor the author. He said the book was quite difficult, it don't have applications and he mentioned a particular and hard problem involving a construction of a Riemannian surface.

---

Edit: The problem of the construction of a Riemannian surface has a infinity product of functions.

Comment: I wonder if it isn't a translation of the collection by Aramanovich et al., A Collection of Problems on Complex Analysis (Dover)? It has increasingly difficult problems taken from several well-known texts.

Comment: @daniel, this is the edition of Aramanovich witch I showed to my professor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Krasnov/Kiselev - Functions of a Complex Variable, Operational Calculus, and Stability Theory:
Problems and Exercises](http://books.google.ie/books?id=hzbvAAAAMAAJ&source=gbs_navlinks_s) (also [here](http://urss.ru/cgi-bin/db.pl?lang=en&blang=en&page=Book&id=18481)).

This is the only MIR problem book in English on complex analysis I'm aware of so but it's probably the [Volkovyskyii](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486669130) book mentioned in the comment above (your professor probably used an old [Pergamon Press](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0080102506) version) which has a good few questions like "construct the Riemann surface" of a root, or log, or log of a sin/tan, etc, a book I'd think of as a MIR book for some reason...